# Div with textarea not staying within page

Tags: html, css

I am currently building a chat window and now I am focusing on the styling part. I have set its attributes to fit any window size. But I am having some issue with the `div id="bottomPanel"`. Inside that div I have a textarea that is overlapping and not fitting in properly. I tried changing the position to  relative but it is not resolving the issue: How can I the `bottomPanel` div to fit properly and get the button to be to the right side? [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/JFLAp/96/)

Something like this :

[image]

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    position: relative;
}
#wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    border: 1px solid #333;
}
#upperPanel {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 100px;
}
#chat {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 200px;
    background: #666;
    overflow: auto;
}
#friends {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 200px;
    right: 0;
    background: #999;
    overflow: auto;
}
#friends ul {
    text-align: right;
}
#bottomPanel {
    height: 100px;
    background: #EEE;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}
#bottomPanel textarea {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    right: 120px;
    resize: none;
}
#bottomPanel input[type=submit] {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    width: 100px;
}
textarea {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the [**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/JFLAp/99/)

[The textarea does not seem to work with absolute position + right + bottom sizing technique](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/absolute-position-textarea). The solution is to use a 100% wide and tall textarea wrapped inside desired size div.

In my example, I recycled `#bottomPanel` instead of adding a new div. I adjusted padding so that its inner dimensions matches the desired size of textarea. The important rules are:

```
#bottomPanel {
    background: #EEE;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    /* CHANGED */
    height: 80px;
    padding: 10px 120px 10px 10px;
}
#bottomPanel textarea {
    resize: none;
    /* CHANGED */
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#bottomPanel input[type=submit] {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put 2 inline divs in the bottom panel. Left and Right the Left is for the textarea, the right is for the button.

Change the `#bottomPanel textarea` to relative and remove the absolute positions.

**Edit:**
Another option could be to just put the textarea in the same div as the chat area, and the button in the same div as the user list.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to achieve is this [`Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/JFLAp/97/).you just did a mistake in arranging textarea